# How to keep footer at the bottom of page under the body content

Tags: html, css, web, jsfiddle

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the footer of all my pages underneath the content of the body. All pages will have different sizes of body content. The challenging bit for me is to keep only one CSS for all pages.

I tried my best showing the css and HTML here but no luck. Instead here is a the JSFiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/zsrsd20m/

```
 .container {
min-height:80%;
position:relative;
}

.titleText{
width:100%;
padding-top: 35px;
padding-bottom: 35px;
background-color: #127577;

color: white;
text-align: center;
}

.navBar{
 padding-right: 20px;
 float:left;
 }

.mainText{
 height:100%;
 padding-left:220px;
 padding-right:250px;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
}

.footerText{  
 width:100%;
 padding-top: 35px;
 padding-top: 23px;
 background-color: #127577;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
```

.Container and all the other Divs made in HTML was made because of this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

I want it so that even if the body content is too small the footer always stays at the bottom of the page. Same applies for if the body content is big. Currently when setting the height of the body content to 100% it shows me a scroll bar even when the content is small and doesnt need a scroll bar. When removing the height it makes the footer directly under the small body content which is half good but its not at the bottom of the page so it looks horrible.

Screenshots of the problems:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrBDA.jpg

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wow - that link's old. We've got some better techniques available these days, namely flexbox.

```css
/* The magic: */
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}

/* Stlyes to make the demo easier to see: */
body { margin: 0; }
header { background-color: #FDD; }
main { background-color: #DFD; }
footer { background-color: #DDF; }
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="Site-content">Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

You can read all about it [right here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Works Nicely! Cheers take your upvote and answer mark

Comment: Please can you check this now the problem with this is the content NOT being next to the navbar instead being a under the navbar. https://jsfiddle.net/mrhc8odL/ @JamesLong

Comment: @Tantrix1 - just put the navbar inside the main content. If you're worried that it won't be the correct height, I think you're looking for the ["Holy Grail" layout](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/)

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this does not appear to work with IE 11...

Comment: @barrypicker - I keep forgetting that browser exists. Add `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to the `.Site` parent (the `<html>` element in the snippet) to make it work

Comment: I've looked eveywhere on the internet for an easy, clean and working solution and this was finally the one that worked! Thanks!

Comment: By far the best one on the internet. Thanks mate.

Comment: This does not work on Microsoft Edge and Firefox when Site-content is populated. Use negative margin-top.

Answer (score 2):

Use sticky footer CSS https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content-inside {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-left">© 2014 - Site Built By Mr. M.
           <a href="" >Test Link</a>
      </p>

      <a href="" class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>Copyright 2017</a>
    </div>
```

Reference: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/easy-sticky-footer